# Loading data after selection in Dropdown in asp.net (VB.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am reading data from a mysql database table.
I have populated a dropdown with the relevant slections, i want the rest of the form to load data once i select the plate number ...

the data is in the same table ...

```
Sub getdata()
    Dim ds_vehicles As DataSet = GetDataSet("select * from tbl_vehicles where fld_ownerSNO='" & Session("logID") & "'", "tbl_v")
    DTPageData = ds_vehicles.Tables("tbl_v")
    ddl_plate.DataSource = ds_vehicles.Tables("tbl_v")
    ddl_plate.DataTextField = "fld_plate"
    ddl_plate.DataValueField = "fld_vno"
    ddl_plate.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub ddl_plate_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddl_plate.SelectedIndexChanged

    'Dim ds_vehicles2 As DataSet = GetDataSet("select * from tbl_vehicles where fld_ownerSNO='" & Session("logID") & "' and fld_vin=" & sel_vno & "", "tbl_v2")
    'lbl_vin.Text = ds_vehicles2.Tables("tbl_v2").Rows(0).Item("fld_vin")

End Sub

Public Shared Function GetDataSet(ByVal cmdStr As String, ByVal tblName As String) As Data.DataSet
    OpenRemoteDataConnection()
    GetDataSet = New Data.DataSet
    Dim sqlcmd As New MySqlCommand(cmdStr, RConn)
    Dim sqladp As New MySqlDataAdapter
    sqladp.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
    sqladp.Fill(GetDataSet, tblName)
    CloseRemoteConnection()
End Function


Public Shared Sub OpenRemoteDataConnection()
    If RConn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Or RConn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Connecting Then RConn.Close()
    RConn = New MySqlConnection(dataFilePath)
    RConn.Open()
End Sub


Public Shared Sub CloseRemoteConnection()
    If RConn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then RConn.Close()
End Sub
```

i am using the ablove class to conent to the datasbe...

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

i am reading/writing to dbase by a class that i have written that works 100%

Comment: No; that does not work 100%.  You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error clearly states, you're trying to do two things with the same connection at the same time.

Either don't share connections or close your data readers, depending on what the problem with your database class is.

Comment: i am using the function GetDataSet in a class to open and close the dbase so the database is not conencted when the selection form the dropdown is made.

Comment: _Don't use a shared connection_.  That's your problem.

Comment: i am closing that shatred connection...     Public Shared Sub CloseRemoteConnection() see code i added above...

Comment: @user1264748: Yes, but if you get two requests at once, your code will fail horribly.  _Don't use shared connections._